# ADT Eclipse Not installing software

Tags: php, eclipse, web, adt

I downloaded the [ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) that is essentially a version of Eclipse with ADT and more already pre installed.

I did this as i got a new development machine and most of my development is Android Apps and Android platform.

I do have a couple of websites to maintain too, so i tried installing the PHP development tools and Web Development tools. While the software installer seems to detect that they are installed the menu system does not.

Installed Versions:

[image: ADT Version]
[image: Installed Software]

[image: An attempt to open the PHP or Web editor]

As you can see eclipse seems to recognise that the PHP and Web editor is installed, but when I come to open the editors, they are not on the list..

Anyone got any ideas why this is happening? (And yes, I have tried restarting eclipse, as the installation specifies!)

This is a Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) 64 bit version of the ADT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

*Note: Previous experience of installing software in Eclipse is required.*

1. Download [SDK Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) again ( only if you have deleted it! )
2. Extract to another location ( E.G. `~/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64NEW` )
3. Open terminal and copy current SDK to new adt-bundle (E.G. `cp ~/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64OLD/SDK ~/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64NEW/.` )
4. Start the newly downloaded version. ( E.G. `. ~/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64NEW/eclipse/eclipse` )
5. Check and install any updates. ( 'Help > Check for Updates' )
6. Install `PHP Development Tools` ONLY (first). ( `Help > Install New Software...` )
7. Install `Web Page Webpage Editor`. ( `Help > Install new software...` )
8. Optional - Delete old bundle ( E.G. `rm -r ~/Development/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64OLD` )

This somehow fixed what ever issue there was. My suspicion is that I managed to download some packages that depended on an update that was not installed. I did read somewhere (lost the link) that this has previously been an issue installing some software within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

While in theory you can install as many plugins into Eclipse as needed, in practice you should **have different installations for different application "clusters"**. So having a mixed Java/Android installation is fine, a mixed HTML/XML/PHP installation is fine, combining all of them (and more) will lead to trouble in the long run.

This is because with the number of plugins increasing, the probability of the plugins having conflicting dependencies increases. Often they *could* perfectly live together in one installation, if the developers had specified some more relaxed dependency versions. But plugin developers often specify a very short version range for dependency (those which they they used themselfes), making it harder for everyone else with a different version.